# Arranging elements with .prependto at less <500px, how to undo when >500px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prepend

Im trying to re-arrange some elements moving some higher up inside their parent element if the screen size is below 500px, to do this im using

```
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
   $("#two").prependTo(".grid");
}
```

My html is like this :

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item" id="one">
  ONE - top when browser >500px
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item" id="two">
  TWO - top when browser <500px
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

But im unsure as to the best way to reverse this if the browser window gets made larger than 500px again ? Would this be done with an `elseif` something like :

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
  $("#two").prependTo(".grid");
} else if ($(window).width() > 700){
   $("#one").prependTo(".grid");
}
```

Or is there a more robust way to write this ?

Comment: Just `else` would do without the extra test. You need to call it from within a window resize event handler of course.

Answer (score 0):

Add resize event to the window element when the size of the browser window changes then your code applies.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

   if ($(window).width() < 700) {
     $("#two").prependTo(".grid");
   } else {
     $("#one").prependTo(".grid");
   }
});
```